# What is wrong in this code? I get a missing terminating '"' error always. Im new to C and wanted this ASCII for CS50x submissions

Tags: c, cs50, string-literals, rawstring

My program just doesn't work. I get this error.

```
population/ $ make test
test.c:6:9: error: missing terminating '"' character [-Werror,-Winvalid-pp-token]
printf(R"EOF(
        ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
2 errors generated.
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
printf(R"EOF(
   _____       _               _ _   _           _   _              _____           _
  / ____|     | |             (_) | | |         | | | |            / ____|         (_)
 | (___  _   _| |__  _ __ ___  _| |_| |_ ___  __| | | |__  _   _  | |    _   _ _ __ ___  __
  \___ \| | | | '_ \| '_ ` _ \| | __| __/ _ \/ _` | | '_ \| | | | | |   | | | | '__| \ \/ /
  ____) | |_| | |_) | | | | | | | |_| ||  __/ (_| | | |_) | |_| | | |___| |_| | |  | |>  <
 |_____/ \__,_|_.__/|_| |_| |_|_|\__|\__\___|\__,_| |_.__/ \__, |  \_____\__, |_|  |_/_/\_\
                                                            __/ |         __/ |
                                                           |___/         |___/
)EOF");
}
```

Comment: You're trying to use something called *raw string literals*. They are not part of C, but exists only in C++.

Comment: By the way, where did you learn about raw string literals? It's not from CS50, that's for sure. While I personally don't hold CS50 in high regards, I do know that it's C part is teaching pure C. Please don't try to mix in other courses or tutorials in your CS50 work. And make sure that whatever other material, books and resources you use to learn don't attempt to teach you another, very different, language.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Hey there. About raw string literals.. I did a lot of googling and Was trying to find how to implement ASCII in C language. While I explicitly mentioned C in my search, some results brought me to a forum similar to this where some dude used R EOF and what not and said it worked for him. I honestly didn't it was for C++ and NOT C. Thanks for clearing that up for me.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Also I wasnt trying to mix in other courses work. CS50s challenging as is for me but I wanted to personify my code and have a bit of *signature* on it so I thought ASCII as a cool watermark type thing. Something I used to see a lot in startup messages of Custom Mods or plugins for various Games and their servers. To me its like a Intro credits but in Programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This construction

```
R"EOF(
   _____       _               _ _   _           _   _              _____           _
  / ____|     | |             (_) | | |         | | | |            / ____|         (_)
 | (___  _   _| |__  _ __ ___  _| |_| |_ ___  __| | | |__  _   _  | |    _   _ _ __ ___  __
  \___ \| | | | '_ \| '_ ` _ \| | __| __/ _ \/ _` | | '_ \| | | | | |   | | | | '__| \ \/ /
  ____) | |_| | |_) | | | | | | | |_| ||  __/ (_| | | |_) | |_| | | |___| |_| | |  | |>  <
 |_____/ \__,_|_.__/|_| |_| |_|_|\__|\__\___|\__,_| |_.__/ \__, |  \_____\__, |_|  |_/_/\_\
                                                            __/ |         __/ |
                                                           |___/         |___/
)EOF"
```

represents a raw string literal the notion of which is defined in C++.

In C such a construction is absent.

Instead you need to write adjacent string literals with new line characters `'\n'` something like the following

```
  " _____       _               _ _   _           _   _              _____           _\n"
  "/ ____|     | |             (_) | | |         | | | |            / ____|         (_)\n"
 "| (___  _   _| |__  _ __ ___  _| |_| |_ ___  __| | | |__  _   _  | |    _   _ _ __ ___  __\n"
  "\___ \| | | | '_ \| '_ ` _ \| | __| __/ _ \/ _` | | '_ \| | | | | |   | | | | '__| \ \/ /\n"
  "____) | |_| | |_) | | | | | | | |_| ||  __/ (_| | | |_) | |_| | | |___| |_| | |  | |>  <\n"
 "|_____/ \\__,_|_.__/|_| |_| |_|_|\\__|\\__\\___|\\__,_| |_.__/ \\__, |  \\_____\\__, |_|  |_/_/\\_\\\n"
```

and so on.

They will be concatenated by the compiler as one string literal.

Pay attention to that in C++ you may insert a character like `\` in a raw string literal and it will be outputted as is but in C you need to use escaped sequence in a string literal like `\\` to output the symbol `'\'`.

Otherwise compile your program as a C++ program.:)

Comment: It doesn't look like your string literals will properly aligned output due to missing spaces.

Comment: @Chris Oh, i have understood why you wrote your comment an down-voted my answer. It is because you already placed you answer to the question.:) Thanks, I will know that.:)

Comment: I can't take credit for the downvote. I never DV answers just because they're "competing" with mine. Only if I think they're fundamentally bad answers. Yours isn't. Though suggesting compiling a C program with a C++ compiler might call for some additional disclaimers.

Comment: Thanks, @VladfromMoscow and Chris for your replies. I have already tried this and it works. I even encountered the Backslash issue so yeah fixing kinda messes up the ASCII but not too much so it is usable. The only thing I'm stuck at now is when I re-prompt the user after an incorrect input the ASCII prints again. So I have to work on the timing and stuff

Comment: @Cyrix No at all. You are welcome. As for your new problem then you can ask a new question providing a minimal complete program that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 6):

String literals in C cannot span multiple lines unless the newlines are escaped.

However, adjacent string literals are automatically concatenated, so the following works:

```
const char *foo = "foo\n" "bar\n" "baz";
```

And since the whitespace between the string literals is insignificant, we can write the following:

```
const char *foo = 
    "foo\n"
    "bar\n"
    "baz";
```

Vs.

```
const char *foo = "foo
bar
baz";
```

As mentioned in comments, you *can* escape the newlines with backslashes. However, in this case you must still remember to insert the newline characters manually.

```
const char *foo = "foo\n\
bar\n\
baz";
```

I am not a fan of this as it prevents indentation of code, which is important for being able to follow control flow and scope.

Comment: @Chris, How is your `"foo\n\
bar\n\
baz"` not 1 _string literal_ spanning multiple lines? "String literals in C cannot span multiple lines." looks contradicted later in the answer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I didnt get half the stuff you said But I have used newline to Implement ASCII in my code. Only problem is the backslashes are a big part of the ASCII and So i had to manually convert them to \\ and remove spaces and so on so much that it ended up kinda messing the ASCII art. But it is kinda still there. Looks messy on some letters but it works